# mongodb unknown argument to $lookup: foreignKey

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to "join" two models (schedule and user) in Schedule aggregate using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), but my response is "unknown argument to $lookup: foreignKey". I'm using Node v8.11.3 and MongoDB 4.0 I'm using I've been searched for days and don't know how to solved this.

**routes/report.js**

```
  Schedule.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                'store': req.body.store,
                'scheduleStart': {
                    $lte: start,
                    $gte: req.body.period
                },
                'status': {
                    $lte: 3,
                    $gte: 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "name": "$customer.name",
                    "cpf": "$customer.cpf",
                    "id": "$customer.id",
                    "phone": "$customer.phone"
                },
                "totalValue": {
                    $sum: "$value"
                },
                "totalServices": {
                    $sum: 1
                },
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'user',
                localField: 'customer.id',
                foreignKey: '_id',
                as: 'user_detail'
            }
        }

    ])
```

**models/schedule.js**

```
const ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
  store: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  customer: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
    phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    cpf: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  }, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created',
    updatedAt: 'updated'
  }
});
```

**models/user.js**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    storeKey: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
    birthday: String,
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cpf: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        passwordHash: String,
        salt: String
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: meu crime foi votar demais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreignKey` field in the $lookup aggregation stage should be `foreignField` per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match.

Comment: Thanks, my response works! but know my array user_detail is empty

Comment: Are you sure the localField being specified (`customer.id `) is right? The $group stage preceding the $lookup is grouping partially on `customer.id` and seems to be renaming it to `_id.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, I tried this, but the array still return empty

Comment: I changed the lookup parameters to:

 `$lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: '_id.cpf',
                foreignField: 'cpf',
                as: 'user_detail'
            }`

cpf is unique in both models and I changed the parameter `from: 'user' ` to `from: 'users' ` in **plural** and works well!